# How to substitute unstressed vowel?

Tags: python

I have a CSV file with the following data:

```
bel.lez.za;bellézza
e.la.bo.ra.re;elaboràre
a.li.an.te;alïante
u.mi.do;ùmido
```

the first value is the word divided in syllables and the second is for the stress.
I'd like to merge the the two info and obtain the following output:

```
bel.léz.za
e.la.bo.rà.re
a.lï.an.te
ù.mi.do
```

I computed the position of the stressed vowel and tried to substitute the same unstressed vowel in the first value, but full stops make indexing difficult. Is there a way to tell python to ignore full stops while counting? or is there an easier way to perform it? Thx

After splitting the two values for each line I computed the position of the stressed vowels:

```
    char_list=['ò','à','ù','ì','è','é','ï']
    for character in char_list:
        if character in value[1]:
           position_of_stressed_vowel=value[1].index(character)
```

Comment: Please share your code so we can see how you are counting and help to get around your current issue.

Comment: What's the encoding of the CSV file?

Comment: If it's encoded as UTF-8, `é` will be two bytes and your indexing might be off then.

Comment: it's UTF-8 but that doesn't seem to generate errors

Comment: in the first case (bellézza) the character with index 4 is é but if I want to change it in bel.lez.za, the character with index 4 is the second l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest merging/aligning the two forms in parallel instead of trying to substitute things via indexing. The idea is to iterate through the plain form and take out one character from the accented form for every character from the plain form, keeping dots as they are.

(Or perhaps, the idea is to add the dots to the accented form instead of adding the accented characters to the syllabified form.)

```py
def merge_accents(plain, accented):
    output = ""
    acc_chars = iter(accented)

    for char in plain:
        if char == ".":
            output += char 
        else: 
            output += next(acc_chars)

    return output
```

#### Test:

```py
data = [['bel.lez.za', 'bellézza'],
        ['e.la.bo.ra.re', 'elaboràre'],
        ['a.li.an.te', 'alïante'],
        ['u.mi.do', 'ùmido']]

# Returns
# bel.léz.za
# e.la.bo.rà.re
# a.lï.an.te
# ù.mi.do
for plain, accented in data:
    print(merge_accents(plain, accented))
```

Comment: Thank you! this is probably the easiest solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to tell python to ignore full stops while counting?

Yes, by implementing it yourself using an index lookup that tells you which index in the space-delimited string an index in the word is equivalent to:

```py
i = 0
corrected_index = []
for char in value[0]:
    if char != ".":
        corrected_index.append(i)
    i+=1
```

now, you can correct the index and replace the character:

```py
value[0][corrected_index[position_of_stressed_vowel]] = character
```

Make sure to use UTF-16 as encoding for your "stressed vowel" characters to have a single index.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the two halfs of the string, keep track of the index in the first half, excluding the dots and add the character at the tracked index from the second half of the string to a buffer (modified) string. Like the code below:

```
data = ['bel.lez.za;bellézza',
        'e.la.bo.ra.re;elaboràre',
        'a.li.an.te;alïante',
        'u.mi.do;ùmido']

converted_data = []

# Loop over the data.
for pair in data:
    # Split the on ";"
    first_half, second_half = pair.split(';')
    # Create variables to keep track of the current letter and the modified string.
    current_letter = 0
    modified_second_half = ''

    # Loop over the letter of the first half of the string.
    for current_char in first_half:
        # If the current_char is a dot add it to the modified string.
        if current_char == '.':
            modified_second_half += '.'
        # If the current_char is not a dot add the current letter from the second half to the modified string,
        # and update the current letter value.
        else:
            modified_second_half += second_half[current_letter]
            current_letter += 1

    converted_data.append(modified_second_half)

print(converted_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ['bel.lez.za;bellézza',
        'e.la.bo.ra.re;elaboràre',
        'a.li.an.te;alïante',
        'u.mi.do;ùmido']

def slice_same(input, lens):
    # slices the given string into the given lengths.
    res = []
    strt = 0
    for size in lens:
        res.append(input[strt : strt + size])
        strt += size
    return res

# split into two.
data = [x.split(';') for x in data]

# Add third column that's the length of each piece.
data = [[x, y, [len(z) for z in x.split('.')]] for x, y in data]

# Put text and lens through function.
data = ['.'.join(slice_same(y, z)) for x, y, z in data]
print(data)
```

Output:

```
['bel.léz.za',
 'e.la.bo.rà.re',
 'a.lï.an.te',
 'ù.mi.do']
```